# "No saved view state could be found..." after doubleclick on logout

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, myfaces, viewexpiredexception, requestscope

I have an application with a logout button. After I doubleclick the button, I get a `ViewExpiredException`:

```
An unexpected exception was caught during processing the request:
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /faces/session-timeout.xhtml
```

My logout method has the following structure:

```
try {
    destroyBackendSession(); // this logs to be successful
} catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
    logError(e);
} finally {
    try { 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(userBean.getPortalUrl());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logError(e);
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
}
```

No error is logged here, so it seems everything is working as expected here.

The bean is request scoped.

Potentially relevant config from my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <!-- Serialization and deserialization of the component tree is a major performance hit.  -->
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
[...]
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/session-timeout.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Ideally, I would like to redirect the user to the portal page after logout, not an error page. (See `userBean.getPortalUrl()` in the logout()-method above)

Comment: did you specified the session time out in your web.xml ?!?

Comment: yes: `<session-timeout>20</session-timeout>`